# cannot place a null value in a not null field

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am having the error message `cannot place a null value in a not null field`. In the target table, the not null fields I have are 'INC' and this is my IF statement is

```
IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15)))='',NULL,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15))))
```

How can I write this IF statement so that it does not send any null values.
The second field is the file load ID which gets generated which I think it's ok based on the information in the file load table.

Comment: Your IF statements returns NULL in case the condition is true. Provide a value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert null values to the table having not null constraints. In your function you are checking for null as well as retrieving the result also as null. Instead of NULL, provide any default value.

```
IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15)))='',Default_Value, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15))))
```

Or you can use Filter transformation and restrict the null values to flow into the target

Comment: Thanks Jim, I have tried IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15)))='',v_ICN,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15)))) and IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15)))='',HEADER_INFO,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,3,15)))). I have also tried exactly as you've written but since the Default_Value is not one of the fields, it does not validate successfully

Comment: I gave Default_Value as an example. You can give the field what ever is applicable. Or use filter transformation to filter out null values before loading to the target

Comment: Actually, i've checked the data and that field has value in it, so it is not null but still giving this error message :                                                                               
 WRT_8229                                                                                                         
  FnName: Execute -- [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Cannot place a null value in a NOT NULL field.